# Sql update query using When condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

The example below apply null values into the field nom for the others id, how can forbid this action so that it does not modify the already existing values ​​and that I do not wish to modify ?

```
UPDATE dbo.a
SET [nom]= CASE
   WHEN [id]= 2  THEN 'uuo'
   else 
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with `else`:

```
UPDATE dbo.a
    SET [nom] = (CASE WHEN [id]= 2  THEN 'uuo' ELSE nom END);
```

But if you just want to update the rows that match, then use `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE dbo.a
    SET [nom] = 'uuo'
    WHERE [id] = 2;
```

No need to attempt to update every row if you know which one you want to change.